# C++11 regex: digit after capturing group in replacement string

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, regex-group

My regex_replace expression uses group $1 right before a '0' character in the replacement string like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    regex regex_a( "(.*)bar(.*)" );
    cout << regex_replace( "foobar0x1", regex_a, "$10xNUM" ) << endl;
    cout << regex_replace( "foobar0x1", regex_a, "$1 0xNUM" ) << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
xNUM
foo 0xNUM
```

I'm trying to get output `foo0xNUM` without the middle whitespace.

How do I guard the group name $1 from the next character in the substitution string?

Comment: This is infuriating. My first idea was to use ${1}, but this is not supported. My next idea was to use a named capturing group - which is not supported. I'm really curious about the correct answer.

Comment: @timgeb - yes, i'm migrating from boost::regex where ${1} worked fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are allowed to either specify `$n` or `$nn` to reference captured text, thus you can use the `$nn` format (here `$01`) to avoid grabbing the `0`.

```
cout << regex_replace( "foobar0x1", regex_a, "$010xNUM" ) << endl;
```

Answer (score 10):

Guvante has provided [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29810807/) to this problem.

**However, is the behavior well-defined according to the specification?**

To start from the conclusion. **Yes, the solution has well-defined behavior.**

### C++ specification

The documentation of [`format_default`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type), which specifies ECMA rules to interpret the format string, points to Section 15.5.4.11 of ECMA-262.

### ECMA-262 specification

According to Table 22 in [Section 15.5.4.11 of ECMA-262 specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11)

> `$n`
>
> The nth capture, where n is a single digit in the range 1 to 9 and `$n` is not followed by a decimal digit. If n ≤ m and the nth capture is undefined, use the empty String instead. If n > m, the result is implementation-defined.
>
> `$nn`
>
> The nnth capture, where nn is a two-digit decimal number in the range 01 to 99. If nn ≤ m and the nnth capture is undefined, use the empty String instead. If nn > m, the result is implementation-defined.

The variable m is defined in previous paragraph in the same section:

> [...] Let m be the number of left capturing parentheses in `searchValue` (using `NcapturingParens` as specified in 15.10.2.1).

### Replacement string in the question `"$10xNUM"`

Back at the code in the question:

```
cout << regex_replace( "foobar0x1", regex_a, "$10xNUM" ) << endl;
```

Since `$1` is followed by `0`, it has to be interpreted as the second rule `$nn`, as the first rule forbids any digit to follow `$n`. However, since the pattern only has 2 capturing groups (m = 2) and 10 > 2, the behavior is **implementation-defined** according to the specification.

We can see the effect of the implementation-defined clause by comparing the result of functionally equivalent JavaScript code in Firefox 37.0.1:

```
> "foobar0x1".replace(/(.*)bar(.*)/g, "$10xNUM" )
< "foo0xNUM"
```

As you can see, Firefox decided to interpret `$10` as taking the value of the first capturing group `$1`, then followed by the fixed string `0`. This is a valid implementation according to the specification, under the condition in `$nn` clause.

### Replacement string in Guvante's answer: `"$010xNUM"`

Same as above, `$nn` clause is used, since `$n` clause forbids any digit to follow. Since 01 in `$01` is less than the number of capturing groups (m = 2), the behavior is well-defined, which is to use the content of capturing group 1 in the replacement.

Therefore, Guvante's answer will return the same result on any complaint C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find a method of simply escaping the space or something so it wouldn't print, but I was unable to.

However, the bit you are trying to add in, could be simply appended to the end of the regex output:

```
cout << regex_replace( "foobar0x1", regex_a, "$1" ) << "0xNUM" << endl;
```

The above line would give you the output you want.

Comment: Thanks Migara.  While true for the example, appending is not an option in my real code.