# Regex replacement capture followed by digit separation

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to learn using regex in C++ and I got this code:

```
std::string s("21\n");
std::regex e("\\b(2)1");   

std::cout << std::regex_replace(s, e, "${1}0 first");
```

I wanna turn

> 21

into

> 20 first

but {} seem not to separate capture '$1' like in C#. What should I use then?

And overall can someone point me to C++ regex library documentation? It seems I can't find one.
Or maybe somebody can point me to a better library with full documentation?

Comment: "can point me to a better library with full documentary?" boost has decent documentation and most of it applies to std as it came there from boost. Anyway please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ doesn't permit the `${1}` syntax. In general, that can be a problem, so sometimes you have to [use a callback instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22617209/560648).

In this particular case, though, you're in luck because the backreference identifier is at most two digits, so with `$01` [you're safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29809811/560648):

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s("21\n");
    std::regex e("\\b(2)1");   

    std::cout << std::regex_replace(s, e, "$010 first") << '\n';
}

// Output: 20 first
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad9e983d83cba7ce))

As for documentation, [cppreference has most of the facts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), but in all honesty the available documentation for `std::regex` is about as esoteric as the feature itself.

Comment: $010 is really the case for this, thank you. I'll mark your post as an answer. But I fear there will rise more and more questions regarding regex as I can't simply understand syntax of writing it.

Comment: @Aleksandr If your questions are about forming a valid _pattern_, there are loads of good resources for that all over the web. If it's about the C++ technology surrounding it, feel free to ask again (after consulting the reference, of course): you're certainly [not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54237547/560648) asking questions about `std::regex` here!